# Is it possible to post a Twitter "tweet" from an small embedded system?

Tags: twitter, embedded

Everything I can find assumes I can use some "large" Twitter API, or run PHP code.  I have a very small platform based on an ARM M0+ bare metal (no OS) and would like the device to post "tweets".

For example, everything I see implies I must connect with SSL -- on this small processor, that is probably possible, but not very realistic.  Nor is dealing with OAuth and such.

My leaning is to create my own "service" on my home server that can accept a username and password and tweet, then do all the heavy lifting to post on behalf of the embedded device but this seems like a cop out to me.

Is it really that hard to post to Twitter?

[Edit: I'm writing the code myself in C at a very low level]

Comment: It's easy to post to Twitter *with* the right tools - there are *many* things that are not practical/possible without the many levels of abstraction/protocols they rely upon available. I would use a proxy.

Comment: I would be far easier and quicker to implement, if you send the data from the MCU to a PC, through some serial bus. The PC program can spend all its time asleep waiting for overlapped IO, only waking up to tweet when the MCU sends something to it.

Comment: If you can afford higher platform's costs you should go with embedded linux in order to simplify the web part of the development.

Comment: I think what I'm seeing here is that it's just not realistically possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd start here:  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

Comment: Okay, I've looked at that, and creating the proper GET/POST information is not too bad, but it still requires https, and OAuth, which is a pain.  Thanks though.

Comment: It's a pain, but there'd be no point in having user accounts if they weren't authenticated.

Comment: I agree, but it just seems a little over the top for what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the answer is: "suck it up princess" - there isn't a well known, light, tweet maker out there.

I'll have to decide if I should proxy my posting through a PC or attempt to support SSL on my wee little board and support the Twitter API.

Thanks for your consideration!